# Spring Batch does not run when importing H2 SQL scripts

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, classpath

I am trying to run a Spring Batch application to create batch jobs.

My `application.properties` as shown below:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:localhost;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=p@ssw0rd
spring.datasource.schema=schema-hsqldb.sql
```

The error I am getting is shown below:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.InvalidConfigurationPropertyValueException: Property spring.datasource.schema with value 'class path resource [schema-hsqldb.sql]' is invalid: The specified resource does not exist.
```

As far as I know, the `schema-hsqldb.sql` exists in classpath `/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-hsqldb.sql`.

The Spring boot application works when I commented out `spring.datasource.schema=schema-hsqldb.sql`. Do I have to manually import the SQL scripts? If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are using the H2 driver with the schema of HSQL. H2 and HSQL are different products. You need to use the schema of H2 as well:

```
spring.datasource.schema=/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql
```

That said, you don't really need to configure the datasource for embedded databases with Spring Boot, the datasource will be automatically configured. Here is an excerpt from the [Embedded Database Support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-embedded-database-support) section of the reference docs:

> Spring Boot can auto-configure embedded H2, HSQL, and Derby databases. You need not provide any connection URLs. You need only include a build dependency to the embedded database that you want to use.